# The code is not able to insert an image into the database because. it does not go past the if statement

Tags: php

The code is not able to insert an image into the database because 
   it does not go past the if statement. When i run the application, 
   i always get "Please Insert a valid image".  I don't get any errors 
   in the code. Please your help will be appreciated.

```
    <form action="uploadtest.php" method="POST" ectype="multipath/form-data">
        <label>Picture:</label><input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Record">
```

```
  <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("testlab");

    //file properties

    if(empty($_FILES) || !isset($_FILES['image']))
    {   
    echo "Please Insert a valid image";

    }//end of if statement

    else
    {   
       $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
       $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
       $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
          if($image_size==FALSE)
         echo "This is not an image.";
          else
         {
        mysql_query("INSERT into testimage VALUES('','$image_name','$image'");
        echo "Image Successfully inserted into the Database";
         }
    }//end of else statement
?>
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: `addslashes()` eh? That's even worse than `mysql_real_escape_string()` which is deprecated. Might want to check the published date on whatever ancient tutorial you're following and think about trying out some more *recent* resources

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your HTML - it should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, not 'ectype' and 'multipath'.

Comment: its now working after changing it to enctype="multipart/form-data" Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ectype="..."` to `enctype="..."` (you are missing the 'n').

Comment: its now working after changing it to enctype="multipart/form-data" Thanks so much for your help, i really appreciate it.